# How to stop alert on lock/unlock event?

Tags: android

I have a service in which I am starting an alert whenever SMS/Email is received, but now I want to stop the alert (if it is playing) once user unlock the screen.

For alerting I am using MediaPlayer class.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: hey, please can you give the details how you use the alert, which is help by MediaPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a BroadcastReceiver which listens for the android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT intent you should be able to see when a user has unlocked the screen:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
      // Stop alert
    }
}

registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT));
```